# In Python, how to deep copy the Namespace obj "args" from argparse

Tags: python, copy, argparse

I got "args" from argparse:

> args = parser.parse_args()

I want to pass it to two different functions with slight modifications each. That's why I want to deep copy the args, modify the copy and pass them to each function.

However, the copy.deepcopy just doesn't work. It gives me:

> TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object

So what's the right way to do it? Thanks

Comment: `copy.deepcopy` seems to work fine on an empty `argparse.Namespace` in python 2.7.10 (and 3.6.0a2) ... Are you sure it's the `Namespace` that is an issue and not the contents of the namespace?

Comment: @mgilson You are right. It's the issue of the contents of the namespace. I just do not know what's the best way to handle this situation as the simple deepcopy doesn't work.

Comment: We can't help you if we know nothing about the contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I myself just figured out a way to do it:

```
args_copy = Namespace(**vars(args))
```

Not real deep copy. But at least "deeper" than:

```
args_copy = args
```

Comment: That's a shallow copy.

Comment: [You probably didn't know what to try to properly test whether the copy was deep.](http://ideone.com/9eH4ln) It's definitely shallow.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right~ What made me thought it was deep is that I did some "not in-place" change of the args_copy  attribute which seems to create another copy of that attribute.

Comment: @user2357112 But at least it turns out to be "deeper" than args_copy=args :)

Comment: Yeah, `args_copy=args` is called things like "reference copy" or "not even a copy".

Answer (score 5):

```
import copy
args = parser.parse_args()
args_copy = copy.deepcopy(args)
```

Tested with Python 2.7.15

Comment: This will definitely not produce a deep copy, a list attribute will not be duplicated.